# MySQL Date difference between two rows with aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a table as

```
id     client_id          date
1      1001               2008-11-26 00:00:00
2      2001               2008-09-01 00:00:00
3      2001               2008-08-31 00:00:00
4      1001               2007-08-26 00:00:00
5      3001               2003-11-26 00:00:00
6      1001               2003-05-05 00:00:00
```

I want to calculate the date difference between two consecutive rows for the same `client_id` and select only `client_id` whose date difference is **greater or equals 30 days**

Comment: provide your expected output in table format

Comment: Or even better, add your current effort.

Comment: What MySQL version you are using?

Comment: MySQL version is 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL < 8.0, where  window functions are not available, consider:

```
SELECT t.*, t1.date next_date, DATEDIFF(t1.date, t.date) date_diff
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN mytable t1
    ON  t1.client_id = t.client_id
    AND DATEDIFF(t1.date, t.date) >= 30
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM mytable t2
        WHERE 
            t2.client_id = t.client_id 
            AND t2.date > t.date
            AND t2.date < t1.date
    )
ORDER BY t.client_id, t.date
```

This query gives you the records whose next record for the same client is more than 30 days later. It works by self-joining the table and applying the following conditions:

- the joined record should belong to the same client
- its date should be at least 30 days greater than the date of the current record
- there should not exist another record for the same client whose date is greataer than the date of the current record and smaller than the datea of the joined record (this implements the concept of *next* record)

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bhBh2gsuUC4PNNdcoYBSaf/2)**:

Your sample data (properly sorted):

```
| id  | client_id | date       |
| --- | --------- | ---------- |
| 6   | 1001      | 2003-05-05 |
| 4   | 1001      | 2007-08-26 |
| 1   | 1001      | 2008-11-26 |
| 3   | 2001      | 2008-08-31 |
| 2   | 2001      | 2008-09-01 |
| 5   | 3001      | 2003-11-26 |
```

Results of the query:

```
| id  | client_id | date       | next_date  | date_diff |
| --- | --------- | ---------- | ---------- | --------- |
| 4   | 1001      | 2007-08-26 | 2008-11-26 | 458       |
| 6   | 1001      | 2003-05-05 | 2007-08-26 | 1574      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Since the MySQL version does not allow the use of the LEAD() function. To search for the next date, I use the query `SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE client_id = t.client_id AND t.id < id LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT client_id 
FROM (SELECT t.*, (SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE client_id = t.client_id AND t.id < id LIMIT 1) AS lead_date
FROM mytable t) t2 
WHERE ABS(datediff(lead_date, date)) >= 30 GROUP BY client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it interesting so did for you,
as I can see the data is dummy and id is bigger for older dates , I am ignoring id field

select * from (
    select client_id,maxs,max(all_dt) as sec,datediff(maxs,max(all_dt)) as diff from (
        select * from (
            select client_id,max(dt) as maxs
            from table_name t
            group by client_id
        )mx
        left join
        (
            select client_id client_id_all,dt as all_dt
            from table_name t2
        )all_
        on mx.client_id=all_.client_id_all
        order by mx.client_id
    )f 
    where all_dt < maxs and client_id=client_id_all
group by client_id
)master where diff >=30

Client id with single date records and difference less than 30 will be not listed in output.

Hope it helps.

Good Luck